# CSS layout - three columns, with the middle column containing two boxes

Tags: css

My current layout looks like this: https://gyazo.com/5ed712dcea7d207b511220e3c73185da

I put A, B and C in the same div and gave them the same class name, and then did a .css file with this:

```
.classname{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

But I want to add D to the bottom of B so the layout looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/4e8cb4cfd3f4011d359bc1e25b717ff1

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any css framework e.g Bootstrap ?

Comment: No, it's for a class, I am writing the code completely from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrapped div B and div D with another div to make it stay together. this is just the way i made it to show you how to handle this kind of layouts. but better way is to use `flex` property of css. other who knows flex well may help with the use of flex.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.classname {
 display: inline-block; 
 vertical-align: top;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.layout {
 height: 100px;
 float: left;width: 31%;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="classname layout">a</div>
<div class="layout">
 <div class="classname" style="width: 100%;height: 70px;">b</div>
 <div class="classname" style="width: 100%;height: 20px;margin-top: 10px;">d</div>
</div>
<div class="classname layout">c</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can solve this problem. The one way you can do is to do like this, Have a look at the code below. but if you don't want to be like this then you may wish to look at masonry layout.

```css
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.elem-left, .elem-right {
   width: 200px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
.elem-left{
  border-right: 0;
}
.elem-right{
  border-left: 0;
}
.elem {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.flex-column {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
}
.flex-column>.elem:first-of-type{
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.elem p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem-left"></div>
  <div class="flex-column">
    <section class="elem">
      <p>
        Flexbox is so easy!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="elem">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget.
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="elem-right"></div>
</div>
```